# Memory leak on calling API using sharedInstance resulting in crashin IOS

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, singleton

I created a `sharedInstance` with the code below:

```
 + (MyClass *)sharedStore
    {
        @synchronized(self) 
       {
            if (sharedInstance == nil)
               sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
        return sharedInstance;
    }
```

I have a function in `MyClass`

```
- (MyClass *)initService:(int)serviceType areaSelected :(int)areaID target:(id)delegate
{

    self = [super init];
    // again init function is called after having a shared instance which is resulting in memory leak.

    if(self)
    {
        jsonParserObject = [[MyClassInfoParser alloc]init];
        if(jsonParserObject != nil)
        {
            serviceTypeRequested = serviceType;

                selectedAreaId = areaID;
                NSString *url = [self createUrlandBodyForService];
                NSLog(@"URL : %@",url);
                if ([Reachability connected])
                {
                    if(url.length)
                    {
                        BOOL status =  [self initRequest:url withDelegate:delegate];
                        if(status)
                            NSLog(@"Request for fields successfully");
                        else
                            NSLog(@"Failed to send request for fields");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         [super responseFailedNotification:nil];
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                [super networkError:delegate];
            }

        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

To call the above function I use the code

```
   - (void)startServiceForInformation
    {
        serviceObj = [[MyClass sharedStore]initService:2 areaSelected:self.areaId target:self];
        [serviceObj start];

    }
```

This is resulting in memory leak which results in crash.Can anyone help me out to fix this memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Why an another init method when using singleton class?There is **no need** for a second init method make that a method and just call it with your singleton instance

Try this

```
- (void)startService:(int)serviceType areaSelected :(int)areaID target:(id)delegate
{
        jsonParserObject = [[MyClassInfoParser alloc]init];
        if(jsonParserObject != nil)
        {
            serviceTypeRequested = serviceType;

            selectedAreaId = areaID;
            NSString *url = [self createUrlandBodyForService];
            NSLog(@"URL : %@",url);
            if ([Reachability connected])
            {
                if(url.length)
                {
                    BOOL status =  [self initRequest:url withDelegate:delegate];
                    if(status)
                        NSLog(@"Request for fields successfully");
                    else
                        NSLog(@"Failed to send request for fields");
                }
                else
                {
                    [super responseFailedNotification:nil];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                [super networkError:delegate];
            }
        }
}
```

and call

```
- (void)startServiceForInformation
    {
        serviceObj = [[MyClass sharedStore]startService:2 areaSelected:self.areaId target:self];
        [serviceObj start];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call [super init] in the second function, assuming these are both on the same class, which I inferred due to your comment.

Since this is an instance function and not a static function like your first, you are calling it on an object. In most cases where you are overriding `NSObject init`, you have a relitively bare object created by the class's `alloc` selector.

In this case, you are just configuring an object which you have already created. Are you sure you need the singleton interface?

Comment: Thanks , I avoided [super init] , this fixed the crash